# Is "improve/enhance formats" proper English?

Tags: word-usage

As we know, when we edit posts in stack exchange, we need to fill `Edit Summary` area:
[image]

---

I didn't realize `improve formats` may not be proper English until searching google *improve formats* and *enhance formats*, then finding few results appear.

To find out the right expression, I looked for others' `Edit Summary` area. Finally, from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15357935/revisions I found *fix formats* is valid.

---

- Is *improve/enhance formats* proper English? (Ok, the answer is virtually *no*)
- If not, why cannot improve/enhance be used on *format*.
- What other kinds of terms cannot use *improve/enhace* to describe?

Comment: Did you try searching "improved formatting" (exactly as it appears), too? There's a big grammatical difference between "improve formats" and "improved formatting." That is, your question isn't invalid, but it doesn't have anything to do with the verb "improve" used with the object "formatting."

Comment: In other words, there's a difference between what "formatting" means and what "format" means. That could make an interesting question. But there's nothing wrong with either _improved formatting_ or _fixed formatting_.

Comment: @joiedevivre I searched "improved formatting" just now. it seems to be proper English. Let me continue to learn the difference between format and formatting from google.

Comment: @joiedevivre I will post a new question about format and formatting(with improve).

Comment: If it helps with your searching, I would mention you'd probably get a lot of hits with "improve **the** format," too.

Comment: @joiedevivre Yes, I found I didn't use quotation when I search `improve formats`. After adding quotation, it has many examples. Now I learn that `improve (the) formats/formatting` are all proper, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are all proper, with slight differences in meaning. But "improve format" without the definite article is weird. While "formatting" might be used with or without it.